# Frequency of each element of an array considering all contiguos subarrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sub-array

Consider an array A = [5,1,7,2,3]

All contiguos subarrays = { [5], [1], [7], [2], [3], [5,1], [1,7], [7,2], [2,3], 
[5,1,7], [1,7,2], [7,2,3], [5,1,7,2], [1,7,2,3], [5,1,7,2,3] }

Replace all the arrays in the above set with maximum element in it:

set will look like this: { [5], [1], [7], [2], [3], [5], [7], [7], [3], 
[7], [7], [7], [7], [7], [7] }

Frequency info:  [5] -> 2, [1] -> 1, [7] -> 9, [2] -> 1, [3] -> 2

My Goal is to find the above frequency info.

**My Approach:**

First make a list of pair (x,y). x is element in A and its index is y.

LIST : [ (5,1), (1,2), (7,3), (2,4), (3,5) ]

Sort the list in decreasing order with respect to first element.Now,

LIST : [ (7,3), (5,1), (3,5), (2,4), (1,2) ]

**Algorithm:**

```
def f( array, first_index, last_index):
       ->select an element from LIST starting from left which
         is not marked as visited and (first_index <= element.second <=   
         last_index)
       ->calculate frequency info of element in tuple as  (element.secondvalue-first_index+1) + (element.secondvalue-first_index+1)*(last_index - element.second_value)
       ->Mark above element as visited
       ->Recursively solve f( array, first_index,element.secondvalue-1 ),f( array,element.secondvalue+1,last_index)
```

We can easily set suitable base case.

Time complexity:O(n*n)

I have tried a lot to come with the above algorithm but unable to improve time complexity.How I can do so?Any hint,approach will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like there is a function that describes this relation

Comment: Related to: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890785/counting-according-to-query). The answer I have provided there would solve your problem in `O(n)`, instead of `O(n log n)` as other answers to this question. I can repost the relevant parts to your question in a new answer here, if you want.

Comment: really in O(n) ! Ofcourse I would like to know .please post it..

Answer (score 2):

Based on Paul's answer, I implemented a O(n log n) version using a simplified version of a segment tree. You'll notice that this answer is the same as Paul's, but with optimized versions of `leftctsmaller` and `rightctsmaller`.

In practice, what it does is to take an array, let's say:

```
A = [5,1,7,2,3,7,3,1]
```

And construct an array-backed tree that looks like this:

[image: segment tree]

In the tree, the first number is the value and the second is the index where it appears in the array. Each node is the maximum of its two children. This tree is backed by an array (pretty much like a heap tree) where the children of the index `i` are in the indexes `i*2+1` and `i*2+2`.

Then, for each element, it becomes easy to find the nearest greater elements (before and after it).

For example, to find the nearest greater element to the left, we go up in the tree searching for the first parent where the value is greater and the index is less than the argument. The answer must be a child of this parent, then we go down in the tree looking for the rightmost node that satisfies the same condition.

I've implemented it in Python (as well as the naïve version, to check the answer), and it seems to work well.

```py
import sys, random
from collections import defaultdict
from math import log, ceil

def make_tree(A):
    n = 2**(int(ceil(log(len(A), 2))))
    T = [(None, None)]*(2*n-1)

    for i, x in enumerate(A):
        T[n-1+i] = (x, i)

    for i in reversed(xrange(n-1)):
        T[i] = max(T[i*2+1], T[i*2+2])

    return T

def print_tree(T):
    print 'digraph {'
    for i, x in enumerate(T):
        print '    ' + str(i) + '[label="' + str(x) + '"]'
        if i*2+2 < len(T):
            print '    ' + str(i)+ '->'+ str(i*2+1)
            print '    ' + str(i)+ '->'+ str(i*2+2)

    print '}'

def find_generic(T, i, fallback, check, first, second):
    j = len(T)/2+i
    original = T[j]
    j = (j-1)/2

    #go up in the tree searching for a value that satisfies check
    while j > 0 and not check(T[second(j)], original):
        j = (j-1)/2

    #go down in the tree searching for the left/rightmost node that satisfies check
    while j*2+1<len(T):
        if check(T[first(j)], original):
            j = first(j)
        elif check(T[second(j)], original):
            j = second(j)
        else:
            return fallback

    return j-len(T)/2


def find_left(T, i, fallback):
    return find_generic(T, i, fallback, 
        lambda a, b: a[0]>b[0] and a[1]<b[1],  #value greater, index before
        lambda j: j*2+2,                       #rightmost first
        lambda j: j*2+1                        #leftmost second
    ) 


def find_right(T, i, fallback):
    return find_generic(T, i, fallback,
        lambda a, b: a[0]>=b[0] and a[1]>b[1], #value greater or equal, index after
        lambda j: j*2+1,                       #leftmost first
        lambda j: j*2+2                        #rightmost second
    )       

def optimized_version(A):
    T = make_tree(A)

    answer = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for i, x in enumerate(A):
        left = find_left(T, i, -1)
        right = find_right(T, i, len(A))
        answer[x] += (i-left) * (right-i)

    return dict(answer)

def naive_version(A):
    answer = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for i, x in enumerate(A):
        left = next((j for j in range(i-1, -1, -1) if A[j]>A[i]), -1)
        right = next((j for j in range(i+1, len(A)) if A[j]>=A[i]), len(A))
        answer[x] += (i-left) * (right-i)
    return dict(answer)


A = [random.choice(xrange(32)) for i in xrange(8)]    
MA1 = naive_version(A)
MA2 = optimized_version(A)

sys.stderr.write('Array:     ' + str(A) + '\n')
sys.stderr.write('Naive:     ' + str(MA1) + '\n')
sys.stderr.write('Optimized: ' + str(MA2)  + '\n')
sys.stderr.write('OK:        ' + str(MA1==MA2)  + '\n')
#print_tree(make_tree(A))
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt your code runs in `O(n^2)`. Anyways, one way to solve this in a more efficient way would be to map each number to the number of items to the left/right which are smaller than the given item. For example:

```
input = [2 , 3 , 1 , 5 , 4 , 8 , 0]
for number n = 5
leftctsmaller(n) = 3
rightctsmaller(n) = 1
```

This map will require `O(n^2)` to generate. The rest is straightforward. Given the space to the left and to the right, we can easily determine the number of subarrays that only contains smaller numbers than `n`, except for `n` itself.

Comment: Can we further improve its time complexity

Comment: @DeepakYadav should be possible. Though I'll have to think about a way for optimizing the search. I'll update tomorrow

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this with segment trees.

Comment: @JuanLopes thanks. this is solution is so simple and yet didn't come to my mind.

Comment: @Paul implemented your idea optimizing the operations using a segment tree

Answer (score 1):

Traverse your value-to-index map from bottom to top - maintain an augmented tree of intervals. Each time an index is added, adjust the appropriate interval and calculate the total from the relevant segment:

```
A = [5,1,7,2,3] => {1:1, 2:3, 3:4, 5:0, 7:2}

indexes     interval     total sub-arrays with maximum exactly
1           (1,1)        1 =>           1
1,3         (3,3)        2 =>           1 
1,3,4       (3,4)        3 =>           2
1,3,4,0     (0,1)        5 =>           2
1,3,4,0,2   (0,4)        7 => 3 + 2*3 = 9
```

Insertion and deletion in [augmented trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Augmented_tree) are of `O(log n)` time-complexity. Worst-case total time-complexity is `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am having hard time trying to explain my solution in words. I will just add the code. It will explain itself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#define max 10000

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    ifstream input("/Users/appleuser/Documents/Developer/xcode projects/SubArrayCount/SubArrayCount/input.in");

    int n, arr[max], before[max]={0}, after[max]={0}, result[max];
    input >> n;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        input >> arr[i];

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (int j=i-1;j>=0&&arr[j]<arr[i];j-=before[j]+1)
            before[i]+=before[j]+1;

    for (int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        for (int j=i+1;j<n&&arr[j]<arr[i];j+=after[j]+1)
            after[i]+=after[j]+1;

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        result[i]= (before[i]+1)*(after[i]+1);

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout << result [i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation for (before[i]+1)*(after[i]+1):**

for each value we need the numbers lies before and less than the value and the numbers lies after and less than the value.

```
  | 0  1  2  3  4  5 .... count of numbers less than the value and appears before.
---------------------
0 | 1  2  3  4  5  6
1 | 2  4  6  8  10 12
2 | 3  6  9  12 15 18
3 | 4  8  12 16 20 24
4 | 5  10 15 20 25 30
5 | 6  12 18 24 30 36
. | 
. |
. |
count of numbers less than the value and appears after.
```

Example: for a number that have 3 values less than it and appears before and have 4 values less than it and appears after. answer is V(3,4) = 20 = (3+1) * (4+1)

please, let me know the results.